# Represent x -> y -> x anonymously?

Tags: functions

Let `f := x |-> y |-> x`, such that `f[a][b][c]` yields `a[c]`.

Is there a way to represent this same construct using only the `#`/`&` form of anonymous functions? That is, without using `Function` or any variable names? (Slot numbers are fine.)

Comment: This has been asked before, albeit in a clearer way. The answer has always been, "No."  Might be hard to track down, unless someone remembers how to find it....

Comment: `ClearAll[g];g=#[[0]]&@(#&);g[a][b][c]`?

Comment: @klgr ah, nice—a clever way of getting `g = Function`! (perhaps a more readable way without violating the rules would be `g = Head[0 &]`, to make it apparent the (second) `#` is doing no work.)

Comment: @kglr Oh, snap, you got it. `#[[0]]&[#&][a][b][c]==a[c]`. I guess the `[[0]]` is iffy, but that's as close as we get. Might as well post that as answer.

Comment: In the _Possible Issues_ section in the documentation for [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) it says _"Use explicit names to set up nested pure functions"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to say `Function` without saying `Function`:

```
h = ☺ & [[0]];

h[a]
```

> ```
>  a&
> ```

```
h[a][b]
```

> ```
>  a
> ```

```
h[a][b][c]
```

> ```
>  a[c]
> ```

Alternatively, as @thorimur suggested in comments, you can use `Head` instead of zeroth `Part`:

```
 h = Head[☺ &]
```

Comment: And for the record: `CurryApplied[#1@#3&,3][a][b][c]==a[c]`

Comment: I am still curious, just briefly, what's the basic problem that prevents this from being properly possible?

Comment: @Trev, by _properly_  you mean using _only_  slots and `&` (no `Function`, `Part`, `Head`, `OperatorApplied` etc)?

Comment: Precisely. Basically, as a rule of thumb, anything you can do without using letters, double brackets, or being sneaky. Is it that you can't control the arity of functions / skip over incoming arguments?

Comment: @Trev I suspect it will boil down to scoping `#`. But I'm not one to delve that far into what is sometimes called runic coding.

Comment: @trev Wait: You want to do it “without…being sneaky’? Or did I misread it? Both yours and kglr’s codes use `Function`. They’re just being sneaky about hiding it behind some syntactic shorthand. It’s really a challenge to actually do this* without `Function` at all.  (*Does “this,” i.e. your problem, mean an expression such that `expr[a][b][c]` transforms to `a[c]`?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that was my original intended challenge/question. I realize `Function` is being surreptitiously called there, that's exactly the sort of thing I meant by "sneaky". To confirm, I am curious if one can implement `f[a_][b_][c_]:=a[c]` while staying away from part selection and named variables (as opposed to slot numbering) and named functions (meaning both user and the built-in library, other than those with shortcuts like `##3`, `@@@`, `/*`, etc., as a first-order measure for purity.)